# Recursive composition in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

In my C++ project I often has the following situation, where I have a Class `A` which has a pointer to the interface of another class `X`.
That class `A` is extended to handle a subtype of `X`. And this situation repeats again.

Note that at each layer the interface changes (new object methods are added, and some others are overloaded), so at each subclass of `A`, the pointer to `X` is cast to the the subclass of `X`

```
+----------+                   +----------+
|          |    A has X        |          |
|   A      +------------------->    X     |
+-----+----+                   +-----+----+
      |                              |
      |                              |
      |                              |
+-----+----+                   +-----+----+
|          |                   |          |
|    B     +------------------->     Y    |
+-----+----+                   +-----+----+
      |                              |
+-----+----+                   +-----+----+
|          |                   |          |
|   C      +------------------->    Z     |
+----------+                   +----------+
```

I wonder if there is any pattern to deal with this situation, or is it intrinsically a bad design?

**EDIT**, consider this structure:

```
+----------+          +----------+                   +----------+
|          |          |          |    A has X        |          |
|    M     <----------+   A      +------------------->    X     |
+-----+----+          +-----+----+                   +-----+----+
      |                     |                              |
      |                     |                              |
      |                     |                              |
+-----+----+          +-----+----+                   +-----+----+
|          |          |          |                   |          |
|     N    <----------+    B     +------------------->     Y    |
+-----+----+          +-----+----+                   +-----+----+ 
      |                     |                              |
+-----+----+          +-----+----+                   +-----+----+
|          |          |          |                   |          |
|    L     <----------+   C      +------------------->    Z     |
+----------+          +----------+                   +----------+
```

This is actually how might application looks. Each level represent a layer in our multi-layered framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this implementation:

```
struct X {};    
struct Y: X {};
struct Z: X {};

class A
{
    // todo: add public interface
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<X> x_;
};

template<typename T>
class AImpl: public A
{
protected:
    T* get() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(x_.get()); }
};

class B: public AImpl<Y>
{
public:
    // todo: add public interface
    using AImpl<Y>::get; // implement rest of B in terms of this
};

class C: public AImpl<Z>
{
public:
    // todo: add public interface
    using AImpl<Z>::get; // implement rest of C in terms of this
};
```

**Edit** (because C needs to inherit from B)

Consider defining B and C as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class BImpl: public AImpl<T>
{
public:
    // todo: add public interface
    using AImpl<T>::get; // implement rest of B in terms of this
};

// this is a new thing (see my explanation on this, below)
using B = BImpl<Y>;

class C: public BImpl<Z>
{
public:
    // todo: add public interface
    using AImpl<Z>::get; // implement rest of C in terms of this
};
```

There is an issue with implementing B like this though: it is poor design to have your classes do more than one thing. In this case, B would have to be both a base class (for C) and a concrete type.

I created a B implementation class to serve as a base. Then, defining B could be either a type alias (my using statement above), or a concrete type specialization:

```
class B: public BImpl<Y> {};
```

Comment: That a good solution for my question. I wonder how can we scale that to multiple composition, please refer to diagram that I added to the edition of my question

Comment: That is not a problem: just add another unique_ptr for M in A, then a second parameter for AImpl and a second get (call them get_x and get_m for example). The rest should stay the same.

Comment: Note that `C` doesn't inherit from `B` as in OP example.

Comment: Right, but `C` needs to inherit from `B`

Answer (score -2):

What you have here is called "the diamond problem" (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)) and it can be solved by using virtual inheritance (see [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)).

```
class InterfaceA
{};

class TypeA: public virtual InterfaceA
{};

class InterfaceB: public virtual InterfaceA
{};

class TypeB: public TypeA, public InterfaceB
{};
```

Do not use a reinterpret_cast to cast i.e. from TypeB to InterfaceA (virtual inheritance has a different memory layout than direct inheritance)

Comment: Where did you see the diamond of death in the OP's example?

Comment: Maybe my diagram mislead you, `-->` means `has a` and `---` means `is a`. There is no multiple inheritance in my question

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted the question and this is no typical diamond pattern. On the other hand it is the same problem. X ist part of A and also a part of Y so if B inherits from A and contains Y then you have two instances of X within your object. If X is the base class of A or just a member of it makes no big difference in the memory layout or the problem itself.